# Timeticker css not working in visjs timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css, plunker, vis.js

I am using [background areas example](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/items/backgroundAreas.html). I have couple of problems

1. In [doc](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/) under `addCustomTime` method description it is mentioned that id is added as classname but any changes to this class is not taking effect.
2. How to center align `content` text in a background area with background area having a border?
3. Also how can I change css for `setCurrentTime(time)` marker?

My css

```
.vis-current-time {
  color: black !important;
  border: 2px;
  cursor: hand;
}

.milestone-1 {
  color: green !important;
  border: 2px;
  cursor: hand;
}

.vis-item.vis-background.positive {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.2);
  cursor: hand;
}

.vis-item.vis-background.negative {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: hand;
}

.vis-item-overflow.vis-item-content {
  left: auto !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Here is [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/6pUagZOPKoBILOq0ysmi?p=preview) of my problem.

**Update**

I am able to center align `content` text to center. I have also updated my plunker but borders are not taking effect

```
#visualization .vis-item.vis-background.positive .vis-item-content {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
  border: 2px;
}
#visualization .vis-item.vis-background.negative .vis-item-content {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution for you.

1) **but any changes to this class is not taking effect:**

You have used the wrong values for that class, so that its not reflected. To change the color you need to use the "background-color" and so on.. see the below CSS code.

```
.milestone-1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 5px;
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
}
```

**2) How to center align content text**

To center align the text apply the CSS for the ".vis-item-overflow" class. No need to add any additional styles.

```
.vis-item-overflow {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**3) Also how can I change css for setCurrentTime(time) marker**

To apply the styles for current time marker you can use the ".vis-current-time" class like below:

```
.vis-current-time{
  background-color: black;
  width: 3px;
}
```

Here is the updated **Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/JVzCoYgltiy6DTL5SOAL?p=preview

Hope this might helps you...

Comment: Thanks that's great, one more thing, how can i have tooltip for background areas, for which content comes from it's data or any other of it's attribute?

Comment: background area means what you mention ? that red color box or Period B ?

Comment: by background areas I mean the red and purple color boxes (without any content i.e., no text like `Period A` but with a tooltip `Period A`) [modified plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5J1zRVhAoY1B8Wq0l5GF?p=preview)

Comment: This is actually an source level issue dut to the positioning, but we can achieve this by the workaround.. please see my below answer..

Answer (score 2):

To apply the tooltip for the whole box you need to add the below CSS style:

```
.vis-background .vis-item-content {
    z-index: 11111;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check the Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JVzCoYgltiy6DTL5SOAL?p=preview

Comment: Thanks it helped, also can the default tooltip be styled only for this timeline, something similar to [this](http://csstooltip.com/)?

Comment: yes, these are the external tooltip plugins... you can use these also, so that you need to include the addition scripts for that plugin..

Comment: This is you need... Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/JVzCoYgltiy6DTL5SOAL?p=preview

Comment: Is there a way to get current time depending on mouse hover on the background area?

Comment: while mouseover on the background, you need the current time in the tooltip or you need to get in the event handler ?

Comment: Anything which lets me use the current time along with some text defined in `title`

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for the previous comment:**

As per vis, we can't update the tooltip dynamically. They initially updated the title at once based on the user input, so we can't update dynamically.

As a workaround we can dynamically update the tooltip from the element. As per the previous update we already used the **`tooltipster`** plugin for tooltip. By using this plugin's open event we can update the title dynamically.

```
 $('.tooltip .vis-item-content').tooltipster({
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
      var currentTitle = origin.data("tooltipsterInitialTitle");
      origin.tooltipster("content", currentTitle + " --- Time :: " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
      continueTooltip();
    }
 });
```

**Demo:** **http://plnkr.co/edit/JVzCoYgltiy6DTL5SOAL?p=preview**

### **Update:**

As per your comment you need to update the time for each second. So you can update the time on particular interval until the tooltip gets visible.

```
  var timer;
  $('.tooltip .vis-item-content').tooltipster({
    position: 'bottom',
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
      continueTooltip();
      updateTooltip(origin);
      timer = setInterval(function(){ updateTooltip(origin); }, 1000);
    },
    functionAfter: function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  });

  function updateTooltip(origin) {
    var newTooltip = getTooltipContent(origin);
    $(origin.tooltipster('elementTooltip')).children(".tooltipster-content").html(newTooltip);
  }
  function getTooltipContent(origin) {
    var currentTitle = origin.data("tooltipsterInitialTitle");
    return currentTitle + " --- Time :: " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  }
```

**Updated Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JVzCoYgltiy6DTL5SOAL?p=preview**

I think this may helps you ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am able to get the current time, but when the cursor moves on the background area, it should update the time as the mouse cursor moves

Comment: Thanks, can you please look at a similar [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722383/angularjs-how-to-change-background-colors-marker-css-and-add-hover-text-on-mar)?